# How does a class loader find a class

Tags: java, classloader

```
ClassLoader c //imagine this is a valid object
c.loadClass(String className, boolean resolveIt);
```

It is the className parameter which is confusing me. I have written the java file to a folder, and compiled it using reflection. I am unsure therfore how I point to the correct file and what naming convention i use for the className.

The documentation sayjust says the name of the class, but how is it supposed to know where it is?

Thanks

Comment: That's what the classpath is for. By the way, it's the fully qualified name of the class, including package hierarchy.

Comment: @Viruzzo - what you say is not correct in the general case. It may be correct for some specific class loader. But there could be class loaders that do it diifferently (for example, get the class data from a database).

Comment: @Ingo I was referring to the default class loader; I think he was interested in the default case, not in the general one.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a `ClassLoader` is precisely to know how to search for class files given a class name. The javadoc says:

> Given the binary name of a class, a class loader should attempt to
>   locate or generate data that constitutes a definition for the class. A
>   typical strategy is to transform the name into a file name and then
>   read a "class file" of that name from a file system.

So, you'll have to make your ClassLoader translate the class name to some location where the byte-code of the class will be found. `URLClassLoader` does that by transforming the class name into a path, and looking up that path in the various jars and directories at which the URLs point.

Answer (score 0):

This is the very reason why you write a classloader in the first place: it is just a mechanism to map class names to (binary) classes in memory. Where the classloader gets the data is its very own business.

For example, an URLClassLoader will consult the class path and see if it can find a file that contains the named class.